# Two URLs, one website, different domains

Tags: rewrite, iis-7.5, web-hosting

We have a website running under `abc.company.com`. We've been asked to make the website available under a different url from a different domain by a customer, let's say `stuff.abc.com`. They've arranged all traffic to `stuff.abc.com` (their server) to be redirected to the IP address leading to the server hosting `abc.company.com` (our server).

The webserver has two IP addresses available (in order to be able to have two SSL certificates and I've setup the bindings as follows:

```
https  [no hostname]    443    10.20.1.50 (with matching SSL certificate)
http   abc.company.com   80    *
```

The above works fine for the old 1 url situation. I added these bindings:

```
https  [no hostname]    443    10.20.1.70 (with a new matching SSL certificate)
http   stuff.abc.com     80    *
```

My question is whether this is correct or that I need to setup URL rewriting. I've also wondered if I should explicitly add the .70 IP for the new domain binding, or that 'all unassigned' is fine.

If I need URL rewriting any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine to me.

No need to specify the IP addresses for the port 80 bindings, the hostnames are sufficient.

You should be able to test this by just hitting the site with the different names.

No need to URL rewrite either.